# Sorting dictionary using a tuple and operator.itemgetter

Tags: python, numpy

I am before my last milestone preparing suitable output. Its quite simple, I think, but my approach doesn't work:

Given an dictionary like

```
mydict = {x1: (val1, dist1, (lat1, lon1)), x2: (val2, dist2, (lat2, lon2)), ...}
```

I tried to sort this in a nested way in an array, first using the "values" and if equals, sorting for "dist".

However, I did my homework and tried it using this way:

```
import operator
s = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

The thing is that if the sort method would be appliable to tuples, it would be quite easy, because it's already in the right order.

Unfortunately I get:

> 'list' object is not callable

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Something is inaccurate or incomplete about the code you posted.  Your example contains no lists.  Please create a working example.  Is it possible you overwrote the name `sorted` with a list value?

Comment: Hey Bren, you are absolutely right. Its overwritten. This is really silly... don't know how to "reassign" the original method. However, can I just click "delete" question in this case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, you can delete your question if you want.

Comment: You can also answer your own question and accept (or let @BrenBarn answer it)

Comment: hmmmmm, probably it will help some others to sort dictionarys or to prevent from using commands like sorted = sorted(...). Really stupid. However, its not my answer. So Bren: Would you? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible you overwrote the name `sorted` with a list value?

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that if the sort method would be appliable to tuples, it would be quite easy

`sorted()` works perfectly fine on a list of tuples, in which case it uses a [lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

> (a,b) ≤ (a′,b′) if and only if a < a′ or (a = a′ and b ≤ b′).

This can be expanded to any number of dimensions.

```
>>> sorted([(10, 1), (5, 3), (6, 5), (3, 2), (5, 10)])
[(3, 2), (5, 3), (5, 10), (6, 5), (10, 1)]
```